# How std::iter_swap invokes std::swap if it passes values?

Tags: c++, stl

I was reading the documentation of some functions and was interested about their standard implementation. I read about swap function that implies that it changes values of two variables only if they are passed as references

```
template <class T> void swap ( T& a, T& b )
{
  T c(a); a=b; b=c;
}
```

That's fine. I am able to pass some variables that are basic types, classes, structures and etc. Of course if a class implements assignment operator in some way.

However I got stuck on this:

```
template<class ForwardIt1, class ForwardIt2>
void iter_swap(ForwardIt1 a, ForwardIt2 b)
{
   std::swap(*a, *b);
}
```

Here this function passes not iterators but their dereferenced values! So, I would assume that swap receives particular values for example 5 and 6 instead some variables. So, where did I mistake?

Comment: `std::iter_swap`: _"...Swaps the values of the elements the given __iterators are pointing to__...."_  https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/iter_swap

Comment: You need to re-read your book about what `*` returns and how references work.

Comment: The iterator's `*` operator returns a **reference** and `std::swap` takes its parameters **by reference** so everything works as desired.

Comment: Ah, right, now I understand. I thought that iterator's asterix returns value that it points to. So it really makes sense if it returns reference